# How to get multiple user_timeline in one single request in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, twitter

Need some help guys. For now, I can successfully get a single user timeline without a twitter account. But I couldn't figure out how to get multiple user time lines in one request.
Actually I just need 3 user timelines via one single request. Any help? Great Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to create a Twitter list of all the users who have timelines you want to request:

More about setting up lists here:

https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists

Here is how to get the timeline for a list:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/statuses

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can I create LIST if I don't have a twitter account setup in my device? Will this be possible? Thanks

Comment: Lists don't require an account on the device to authenticate the request. You will need to use your own Twitter account to create the list, but just make it public.

Comment: Hey, where can I find the slug and list_id of my newly created LIST? Sorry, I'm really lost ... Thank you so much ...

Comment: It should just be the last part of the URL for the slud. Example: https://twitter.com/#!/Scobleizer/most-influential-in-tech would be "most-influential-in-tech"

Comment: and for the list_id? Thanks Again